# php class static variable inside double-quoted string

Tags: php

While this works:

```
class foo
{
    public $name = 'john';
}

$foo = new foo();

echo("hello {$foo->name}");
```

This doesn't:

```
class foo
{
    public static $name = 'john';
}

echo("hello {foo::$name}");
```

```
Undefined variable: name
```

Is it possible to use static class variables within a double quoted string? If yes how?

Comment: All explained under https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

Comment: @CBroe thank you for the link which I reviewed. However I can't find that case in there.

Comment: @Cid right, same question but from 11 years ago. Any chances this is possible in php 7.x?

Comment: You have answer in the first link provided in the documentation: "Using single curly braces ({}) will not work for accessing the return values of functions or methods or the values of class constants or static class variables.". Just use concatenation or printf.

Comment: @blahy thank you for your input, so it's not possible at all or just not with single curly braces? it would be great if that could work somehow without resorting to concat or other hacks

Comment: You have one answer in the linked question that makes this possible with anonymous function in a variable but I dont think this is any good. You can assign this static to a variable and use this variable in your string. I dont think there is a way to do this directly, but I still think concatenation or sprintf is a better/cleaner solution than this syntax and definitely not a "hack".

Comment: @blahy thank you for your time, if not possible to do directly then concat and sprintf are definitely cleaner.